# "No database selected" issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, registration

My developing environment is based on EasyPHP 12 and PHPdesigner on windows XP SP3.
I am working on a registration / login solution, and I successfully completed the "sign up" part of it with a very basic script that used to work fine. For some reason I had to switch machine and, when I copied all the pertinent files back to my first station, I have got the "No database selected" message. I have tried everything to fix the issue, including creation of a brand new DB with only one table so far (users). 
My Connection file (db_connection.php) is as follows:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'superuser'); 
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'hf_databank');

// Make the connection:

$db_connect = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($db_connect))                        {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

// Let us select the database (just in case you want to change it): 

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db ($db_connect, DB_NAME) OR die;
```

and it seems to work fine.

Then, going back to my index.php file, it looks like the following validation lines are creating issues that I am not able to fix:

```
include_once '../includes/db_connection.php';
include_once '../includes/functions.php';

$action = array();
$action['result'] = null;
$text = array();


//check if the form has been submitted

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){

//cleanup the variables  and prevent mysql injection (this uses the function "clean" defined in functions.php file)

    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    $email = clean($_POST['email']);


    //Validation 1: Let’s say the user submits the form without a username. Our statement is going to run the 
    //code below. 
if(empty($username)){ $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please set a  valid username'); }
if(empty($password)){ $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please define a password'); }
if(empty($email)){ $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please set a valid email address'); } 




     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error()); // mySQL Query    
        $row = mysql_num_rows($query); // Checks to see if anything is in the db.


       if ($row > 0) { 
            $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'existing username/email; 
            }
```

it looks like the script is stuck at the "$query" step, where I get the error message.

I have tried several approaches to pinpoint the issue but still not able to understand where the problem is. I am also able to connect to the database (hf_databank) without a problem, database structure looks ok. Any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: you are using mysql_query instead of mysqli_query, use mysqli* version and try

Comment: Where did you create database?Did you set any user name and password ?Tell me as soon as possible.

Comment: You have `mysqli` in one of these and the awful `mysql_query` in the other. Why not use `mysqli` in both? Seeing functions like `clean` is extremely worrying since they're hardly ever implemented correctly.

Comment: @Asraful: Yup I have set a connection with a local MySQl server that works just fine (username: superuser, password: password)...as I said I am completely able to connect to the database using these credentials and manipulate records...for some reason when I try to run a mysql_query from PHP it says "No Databse selected" :(

Comment: @tadman: yes I know about the issue with mysql_ and msqli_ forms, and I will change those, but I do not think this is the reason of my problem with database selection (since the exact same script was working fine few weeks ago...)...anyhow, I will update the code, but do you see anything else that is wrong ? Regarding the "clean" function I appreciate your comment but I tried to temporarily keep that out and I get the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

in the second part you are using mysql_ and to connect you use mysqli_

use mysqli_ also for your query

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'") or die (mysqli_error()); // mySQL Query    
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Use placeholders, please. Without that you're at serious risk for SQL injection bugs.

Comment: @user2997718: I have switched everything to mysqli_* still having the same error popping up :(

Comment: sorry had misspelled $dbconnect changed it now to $db_connect

Answer (score 0):

If it was working properly in your previous machine then I think this solution may help you to select database.
Check step by step the information step by step
[image]

Comment: This looks interesting...but I cannot see a link here...might you help ? Thanks :)

Comment: Where can you not see a link explain me please!

Comment: please drag and drop the image in the new tab to visible! or save the image at first and see it

Comment: you are totally right...the image was actually already self-explanatory but I could not see the arrows clearly....my apologies and thank you very much for taking the time to make all that for me !

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the `mysql_*` used in your script and replace it with `mysqli_*`.

For example :

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'"");
```

I'd suggest you to use the MySQLi class for the connection. It makes coding easier! And especially **secure** by the use of placeholders (?). For more info, visit [PHP.net - Prepared Statements in MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

And also, `mysql_*` is deprecated. So, its better to leave old practices of using them!

Comment: OK ! I fixed it, although I ma not sure what made the trick. However I have done 2 things: \

Comment: 1) I have switched the entire script from mysql_* to mysqli_* format

Comment: 2) I have re-added the superuser to the database in the "new" machine, granting full privileges and flushing everything after that !  Thank you everybody for the great support and suggestions...no more mysql_* version from now on :)

Comment: @Diego Great job! :) I recently switched to PDO. You could have a look at that, whenever you're free!